# Fetching posts belonging to multiple categories and their subcategories brings duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch all posts belonging to multiple categories and their subcategories on a category page in PHP/MySQL. I have three tables involved in this operation with following structure/sample data:

**tb_categories**

[image]

**tb_posts**

[image]

**tb_posts_to_categories**

[image]

The PHP code along with the SQL query to fetch all the posts belonging to a main category and its subcategories is:

```
public function get_all_posts_by_category(&$output, $category_id)
{
    // Build database query
    $sql = "SELECT `p`.*, `ptc`.`post_id`, `ptc`.`category_id`, `c`.`category_id`, `c`.`category_name`, `c`.`category_url`  
FROM `tb_posts` AS `p` INNER JOIN `tb_posts_to_categories` AS `ptc` ON `p`.`post_id` = `ptc`.`post_id` INNER JOIN `tb_categories` AS `c` ON `ptc`.`category_id` = `c`.`category_id` 
WHERE `c`.`category_id` = $category_id AND `p`.`post_status` = 1 ORDER BY `p`.`post_id` DESC";

    // Execute database query
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);

    if(is_array($rows))
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
    }

    // Build database query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = $category_id";

    // Execute database query
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);

    if(is_array($rows))
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $category_id = $row->category_id;
            $this->get_all_posts_by_category($output, $category_id);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

On a category page, I call above function as:

```
    // Get all posts of a category and its subcategories
    $posts = $post_obj->get_all_posts_by_category($output, $category_id);
```

Which yields me following result in an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 5
            [post_name] => Post 5
            [post_url] => post-5
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Nature
            [category_url] => nature
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 2
            [post_name] => Post 2
            [post_url] => post-2
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Nature
            [category_url] => nature
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 1
            [post_name] => Post 1
            [post_url] => post-1
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Nature
            [category_url] => nature
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 5
            [post_name] => Post 5
            [post_url] => post-5
            [category_id] => 3
            [category_name] => Lakes
            [category_url] => lakes
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 4
            [post_name] => Post 4
            [post_url] => post-4
            [category_id] => 3
            [category_name] => Lakes
            [category_url] => lakes
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 3
            [post_name] => Post 3
            [post_url] => post-3
            [category_id] => 3
            [category_name] => Lakes
            [category_url] => lakes
        )

)
```

Clearly, we can see we get one duplicate records for `[post_id] => 5` because post with id 5 was assigned to two different categories - category 2 (Parent category - Nature) and category 3 (Child category - Lakes). But on a main category page (nature), I have Post 5 twice in the foreach iteration.

How can I avoid these duplicate records? What will the correct SQL query or what adjustment I need to make in my PHP function to fetch only unique records? Please help me on this guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fetch all sub-categry-ids of parent-id and place them all in a simple array. Then use `in()` into query with `distinct` selection. Please have a look below:

```
public function get_all_posts_by_category(&$output, $category_id)
{
    //Array of categories with parent category at top
    $cats = array();
    $cats[] = $category_id;

    //Fetch all sub categories
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = $category_id";

    // Execute database query
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);

    if(is_array($rows))
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $cats[] = $row->category_id; //Push category id to array
        }
    }


    // Build database query to fetch posts
    $sql = "SELECT distinct `p`.*, `ptc`.`post_id`, `ptc`.`category_id`, `c`.`category_id`, `c`.`category_name`, `c`.`category_url`  
    FROM `tb_posts` AS `p` INNER JOIN `tb_posts_to_categories` AS `ptc` ON `p`.`post_id` = `ptc`.`post_id` INNER JOIN `tb_categories` AS `c` ON `ptc`.`category_id` = `c`.`category_id` 
    WHERE `c`.`category_id` in (".implode(',',$cats).") AND `p`.`post_status` = 1 ORDER BY `p`.`post_id` DESC";

    // Execute database query
    $rows = $this->get_by_sql($sql);

    if(is_array($rows))
    {
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work either. I tested it and it is still giving me post id 5 twice.

Comment: We don't need `DISTINCT`. Rather than we should use `GROUP BY \`ptc\`.\`post_id\`` to avoid duplicate post id 5 in array.

Comment: Your result is fetching category name, id and url for example `Post id: 5, Category Id : 2` AND `Post id: 5, Category Id : 3` . If you want to fetch post id 5 once then which row you want to fetch ? with category id 2 or category id 3. Or category id,name,url is useless in this query?

Comment: No they are not pointless. They have further usage in my project for making liking to category/subcategory pages. Well, I still think `GROUP BY` is right workaround. Removing `DISTINCT`, nothing happened. I can not decide prior which row I want to fetch. However, your logic to get subcategories and using them in the query with `IN()` is great. It really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have post id 5 then you have to sacrifice for either of one category in result set of this query.

Comment: Ok i understand but how?

Comment: that can be done with group by instead of distinct. Group By post_id

Comment: Ha. That's what I have already done. But I couldn't understand the use of distinct.

Comment: Yes, that is the only solution can be used in yours situation.

Comment: Is there any post in regards to my problem on sto or web so that I can see some other alternatives.

Comment: I dont think so :) if you find my solution useful can you please voteup ?

Comment: Yes sure. But I am waiting for other people to give answer to it else I will vote you up tomorrow.